# warning - Function make_blobs is deprecated

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I wanted to draw a scatter plot of forge datasets, I met an error about function `make_blobs`:

```
FutureWarning: Function make_blobs is deprecated; 
Please import make_blobs directly from scikit-learn warnings.warn(msg, category=FutureWarning).
```

I tried to solve this problem by writing `from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs`, but it's not effective. My code is below:

```
import mglearn
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you do not get an error (i.e. your program does not halt), but just a *warning* - and a warning about the *future*, for that matter.

Having clarified that, in scikit-learn v0.22.2, `from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs` does **not** produce any warning:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
# 0.22.2.post1
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
# works OK, no warnings
```

Even in the current (0.24.1) version of scikit-learn, there is no indication of `make_blobs` being (or soon to be) deprecated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html).

According to [this Github thread](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/issues/113) and [this older SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246784/import-make-blobs-from-scikit-learn), the issue seems to be related to the `mglearn` package, and not to scikit-learn. Indeed, the warning comes from the `make_blobs` function of `mglearn`, which is actually [called by `make_forge()`](https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/blob/master/mglearn/datasets.py#L14); from its [source code](https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/blob/master/mglearn/make_blobs.py#L9):

```
@deprecated("Please import make_blobs directly from scikit-learn")
def make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=2, cluster_std=1.0,
               center_box=(-10.0, 10.0), shuffle=True, random_state=None):
```

In any case, and according to the [`mglearn` package creator](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/issues/113#issuecomment-642782124) in the Github thread mentioned above, you should **not** worry about the warning, and updating `mglearn` will resolve it:

> yes that's fine. You can update mglearn to get rid of the warning though.

Comment: Thanks, its a good anwser, my problem is solved.